More robust MOSFET gate: Which parameter to watch?
Are there N-MOSFET parameters which indicate a more robust gate, able to better withstand ESD, too high or too low voltage (at the gate) and be less prone to fail?
The question is NOT about how to protect a N-MOSFET gate. Advice and suggestions are always welcome, of course, but the question is not about that.
The question is about reading the data sheet to find parameters indicating a less fragile MOSFET gate.
First, I used MMBF170L, then I used the DMN6140L because it has a much lower rdson and higher current rating. Both suffered the same fate: Drain shorted with the source, sometimes slightly, sometimes a lot, but never totally.
The N-MOSFET gate is connected to a very long cable (~10m CAT5). Voltage applied to gate is 15Vdc. No frequency, no PWM: Only manual on-off.
I suspect ESD, but switch bounce due to hardware switching is also suspected. I noticed that a 10K followed by a 15V zener somewhere between the switch and the gate resistor, followed by a 1K gate resistor just before the gate helped (for how long, I don't know). But a zener without the 10K before it was not enough to protect. I was surprised that the zener seemed to have no effect. There are also other protections upstream, at the switch, i.e for debouncing. We noticed very strong ESD, static electric sparks, during the installation. That's why I suspect ESD, but it can also be the effect of the long wire... or something I don't know.
But again, the question is not about how to protect the gate, but which MOSFET parameters to look at.
And is the the DMN6140L specifically weak in this regard?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Isn’t the problem you are holding mosfet too much time in linear region? Just when I see 10k in gates. Look SOA how much time it can be in linear without second breakdown. What the load is?

@MichalPodmanický This is a possibility. Not from the 10K resistor (in fact it did help protect the MOSFET) but from the debouncing circuit, which is not shown here. But I have used the same debouncing circuit in similar situations before without any issue. With 15V input, I don't think it stays long in the linear region even with a slow rising time due to debouncing or other protections.

Answer later maybe. Higher maximum rated gate voltages correlate with increased robustness. Most are 20 volts as is yours. Zener AT FET recommended perhaps in addition to the ones you show. Low gate drive is a bad idea. You can calculate or measure switching time and dissipation.

"The N-MOSFET gate is connected to a very long cable (+-10m CAT5)." This is something that you should avoid, absolutely avoid. A MOSFET's gate needs to be driven by a low-impedance source, at all times. Consider the entire circuit (pos. gate drive supply, driver, gate, source, back to driver, neg. gate drive supply). Also consider the Miller (drain-to-gate) capacitance, injecting charge from the drain to the gate when the gate rises. This might try to keep your MOSFET on while the gate driver wants to turn it off. 10 meters is way beyond what you should aim at. Use 10 millimeters.

You can build a competent gate driver with two very ordinary small bipolar transistors. I can provide a circuit if you don't turn it up with a web search. I have used this with great success in hundreds of thousands of products.

I think this is important - you have specifically said that you do not want design advice but only information on how to select a rugged mosfet. I understand your AIM but ruggedisation will only achieve a very small gain at best whereas competent circuit design at minimal cost will achieve bulletproofness.

Maybe the rugged MOSFET suitable for use on a very long cable can be found in the "Electromechanical Parts / Relays" section of your preferred electronics parts catalog? This is actually not meant to be as sarcastic as it might sound. Depending on your needs, a relay might actually be the best choice. Also, I hope that in your schematic, the LED symbol is meant to indicate an LED with an internal series resistor. Otherwise, the LED and MOSFET on the 27 V supply might be the source of your failure.

@zebonaut Yes there are self-protected MOSFET and MOSFET drivers which I could use in a future version of the device.

There are two main situations as I see it here, and two additional circumstances that are mostly/completely undefined yet reasonably suspect.
Situations
Handling ESD
For a part not in circuit, this falls under the Charged Device Model (CDM) test, such as published in ANSI/ESDA/JEDEC joint standard JS-002.  Capacitance and energy are small, but risetime is fast.
Typical scenarios relate to handling parts in their packaging: this may include partial discharge across charged surfaces of non-dissipative packaging (that staticy sound you get when rubbing plastic; discharge can occur near/around (induced ESD) and through (direct strike) the device in question), or charge due to handling or removing the part from its packaging (triboelecticity), that isn't dissipated due to it not being in contact with said packaging anymore (e.g., dumping parts out of a tape or bag, bouncing on the table, etc.).
HBM (Human Body Model) is also likely (touching, moving, placing, etc. parts), hopefully at lower voltages.  Where ESD controls are in place (say, using a grounded table, dissipative mat, and wrist strap), voltages under 300V are typical, which most parts are rated for.
ESD is a typical datasheet parameter, so we are done here: it's specified directly.
Wired ESD
For a part in circuit, we test the system to IEC 61000-4-2, at various levels as needed, or to other standards as applicable (automotive applications might use ISO 10605, etc.).  Typical commercial equipment is tested at 6/8 or 8/15 kV (contact / air discharge).  The pulse waveform has a rapid rise (contact discharge, couple ns; air discharge, ~10ns), and a duration of 50ns or so (50%-50%).
To a second order approximation, the equivalent circuit of an ESD generator is an RLC series circuit.  The capacitor is charged to some initial voltage (the nominal rating of the test), and the circuit is closed onto the EUT (or nearby objects and surfaces: coupling planes, capacitive clamps, connectors, etc.) via a high-voltage switch (contact discharge) or air spark (air discharge).  The RLC circuit defines a peak current \$I_{pk} \le \frac{V_{pk}}{Z_o}\$ where \$Z_o = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$, and also \$I_{pk} \le \frac{V_{pk}}{R}\$ (because both inductance and resistance act together to increase the loop impedance).  Typically R = 330Ω, so a 8kV test can deliver 24A peak.
As the ESD pulse travels, it inevitably dissipates.  This is truly a light-speed phenomenon, with such short risetimes in question.  An ESD strike to a wire, has it radiating away high-frequency components, inducing charge or current in nearby elements.  A strike to a plane, spreads it out in both directions, as the energy propagates along and around the plane.  The capacitance from plane to EUT can couple significant energy in, and in unexpected routes -- truly, the EUT is bathed in an electromagnetic pulse (EMP), and if energy can find a way in, it will.
At greater distances through space (say, several m), the severity of the pulse is greatly reduced.  Even conducted along cables, it's likely to round off (slower risetime) and attenuate, and after some 10s of m, it may no longer look like ESD anymore.  (Mainly due to the dispersive effect of real cabling installations: cable trays, raceways, etc., or branching circuits like mains wiring; and the high-frequency absorption of common jacket and insulation materials, like PVC.)  Energy is also dissipated in the sense of, being spread out into other modes: the waveform may pick up various squiggles as different cables and structures in the environment resonate from the strike; this has the general effect of softening the peaks; basically, more voltage and charge is distributed over more surfaces, with more oscillation at more frequencies, and peaks at any given location are diluted as a result.  (Though sometimes, the "perfect storm" of reflections comes together and makes peak voltage/current even worse at some particular point in the system -- potentially even at some distance from the ESD gun itself.  Not saying it's likely, just saying it's possible.  For a contrived example, consider a pair of parabolic reflectors, with the ESD gun at one focus.)
For a situation like yours, a strike to either cable, or a strike to metal nearby either cable route, will introduce significant energy to the section of the circuit in question.
For the MOSFET, we need to know what voltage and current are imposed on it.
A direct ESD strike, from ESD gun, into one terminal, out the other to ground -- a very simple system, no wiring at all -- can only be dealt with by shorting out the pulse (or by withstanding its full voltage -- but we can discount that possibility for essentially all discrete semiconductors :) ), and enduring the peak current for the pulse duration.
For D-S or S-D strikes, many parameters are relevant: maximum or breakdown voltage, maximum (pulsed) current, rate of rise (dV/dt), drain capacitance (Coss), and maximum gate voltage and D-G (Crss) and G-S (Ciss - Crss) capacitances.  Violating any one of these ratings, whether directly, or by way of the capacitance dividers implied by the parameters, and device failure is expected.
Note that MOSFET capacitances vary wildly with terminal voltage, in particular with VDS.  The tabulated values are irrelevant here: we must model the effect of the ESD pulse upon the device, causing voltages to rise, capacitances to fall, voltage rises faster, etc. etc.  This is easiest done by preparing a representative model of device capacitance (say in SPICE) and connecting it to a pulse generator.
For a direct G-S (or G-D) strike, mostly gate capacitance and spreading resistance are implicated.  The spreading resistance is rated as a lumped equivalent, but it's due to the distributed resistance between MOS cells on the actual chip.  Therefore, the voltage drop across it is relevant.  Even large power MOSFETs with a few ohms RG, this parameter is relevant: 24A peak * 2Ω = 48V, well over the VGS rating (which might be 20 or 30V; actual breakdown might occur anywhere from 30 to 100V -- you never really know until the instant it blows through).  Even without resistance, gate capacitance must be truly massive to have significant effect against ESD: ignore the R and L in the ESD generator equivalent circuit for a moment and consider the capacitive divider, between the say 150pF at 8kV, and a CGS at 0V initially but rising to no more than say 30V.  To have such an outcome, CGS > 40nF.  That's a big chip.  Such devices do exist -- but keep in mind, considering the above, it'll have to be even bigger (perhaps 100nF or more) to have a good chance at withstanding a direct hit, when including the effect of resistance.
A marginal capacitance also can't withstand two or more direct strikes, which would continue to charge it up.
It is for this reason, by the way, that power supplies are generally ESD safe, as a direct target, or by way of clamping diodes (at least, in the differential mode; mind that there can always be extenuating circumstances that take priority).  With a few µF shunting the supply, and a short distance from any strike target to bypass capacitors, the transient overvoltage can be quite modest (a few V).  For low-power circuits, a clamp diode (TVS) may still be desirable to discharge any excess, as it could still get overcharged by repeated strikes; but most stuff that isn't minding its power consumption will have no problem from that.
But we also aren't asking about a bare MOSFET.  There is more to consider:
Circumstances
Is the wired ESD due to strikes on or near the cable?
Direct strikes, conducted, we can expect fairly large currents crossing the circuit.
The equivalent circuit of cables through space, has the pulse imposed on their characteristic impedance (a cable loosely over / near a ground plane, likely has an impedance from 50 to 150Ω; in free space, maybe 200 or more, or the concept of characteristic impedance starts to lose meaning by then), and propagating up and down the cable from the strike point.  This provides some voltage division, and perhaps a 8kV strike is reduced to 2-3kV on the cable.
As discussed above, the risetime may slow, or ringing is introduced, depending on losses in the cable, what it's routed near, etc.
In transient terms, from any point on a cable, looking left and right, there's a source impedance of Zo, going into a load impedance of Zo; so we expect peak voltage and current on par with this (i.e., a few kV and maybe 8-15A).  Note this propagates in the common mode, around outer shield if applicable, or shared among conductors if not.  We might have a situation like so:

Suppose some part of the circuit is struck with ESD.  The pulse almost instantaneously raises the voltage on direct and nearby wiring, and propagates outward from it.  The whole system becomes energized in turn, at some point in time; the pulse waveforms shown at various points suggest the time delay along cabling, as well as possible reflections picked up from various ends (whether reflecting off bulky units like PSUs or actual ground points, or open circuits like the far end of the LED cable, perhaps).
Notice that we have similar situations for induced ESD, i.e. striking a nearby object, to which the cable has some capacitive coupling, or characteristic impedance.  The pulse has a differentiated waveform, with positive and negative peaks, but the impedance is still determined by cabling and the amplitude isn't much lower (depending of course on how well coupled the objects are).
Don't overlook the effect of the switch itself.  Mechanical contacts close in a fraction of a nanosecond; this launches a wave down the 15V cable, in both directions, and when it whips off the far end (your R3) the voltage doubles up to 30V peak.  (This can be even worse with nonlinear capacitors, as is particularly common in power supplies.)  If this were direct wired to the gate, destruction would be likely, even in the complete absence of ESD.
Is the wired ESD damage due to poor layout?
Consider the EUT section in detail.  There are wires entering and exiting the area:

Note that ESD manifests as a (direct or capacitor-coupled) transient, into any wires of the cable.  As mentioned: the outer shield if applicable, otherwise most wires within (as shown).  This can be considered a Thevenin source with respect to some ideal reference plane (ground hashing in the diagram), but notice you do not, in general, have any connection to that reference plane in your actual circuit: your circuit is distant from it, and at these time scales, pure distance alone is sufficient to violate our usual assumptions of ideal grounding.
Cables themselves have distributed capacitance to ground (or other surroundings), as shown at B, on the right, etc.
Now consider the in-circuit ground.  If this is made with a solid plane (and some other considerations to component placement), we can expect very low inductance along it, and the AC/transient voltage drop from A' to B to C can be very low (as seen from within the circuit).  Thus we can treat ESD entirely as differential mode, with respect to this circuit reference plane, and are only concerned with what wires A and C' are doing.
If ground is made poorly (point-to-point wiring, large loops, etc.), inductors L1-L3 are significant compared to the amplitude and risetime of the pulse, and drop significant voltage (10s, 100s V even).  Remember, the risetime is short, a few ns, so along the length of a cable, voltage rises from 0V to a few kV over maybe a meter (or less!).  If the zener diode is connected as shown (midway between ground points), considerable voltage can drop in the loop with it and the MOSFET, destroying it.  Notice this applies even if wire A is disconnected!
Keeping the gate loop short (Z1, R2, Q1) is paramount for Q1 survival.  A TVS on C' may also be desirable, for the same reason (when Q1's drain/channel isn't suitably rated for ESD strike).
Best Practices
To summarize:

Keep ground paths short, and priority loops small.  Priorities around a MOSFET switch are G-S and D-S circuits.
Use ground plane layout techniques.  Avoid coupling from loose wires or traces, into critical sections of the circuit.
Use resistance to dampen ringing and increase cable/ESD impedance.
Use TVS or clamp diodes (where applicable) to shunt ESD around sensitive circuits/elements.
Use filtering to slow risetime, and provide radio-frequency (RFI) immunity.


Comments should not be used for nice answer type responses. The rules say. Sometimes and answer is so beautiful that it transcends mere  rules. I'll mention this in a technical group where it should be duly appreciated. Many thanks

Thanks for these explanation and suggestions. Thanks also to @TonyM. Instead of adding components over components, if I have to redesign the circuit, I will use a MOSFET driver or a self-protected MOSFET (I just discovered that they exist), all  JDEC (HBM, ESD...) certified . Self-protected MOSFET have more limitations with Vgs and other things. There isn't a wide choice and they are all very similar to each other. Gate Drivers offer more flexibility at the cost of more component and money, but not that much.

The only MOSFET specification which might offer a clue about gate robustness is maximum \$V_{GS}\$, from "Absolute Maximum Ratings". ESD will kill any MOSFET, regardless of that specification.
The zener diodes in your schematic do not offer much protection from ESD, as they are not connected directly to the gate and source. A typical ESD event can incur many amperes of current, which through 1kΩ resistors R1 and R2 would develop many thousands of volts, well beyond the tolerance of even the most robust of MOSFETs. To mitigate ESD, the diodes would have to be connected directly between gate and source.

You show a 15 V drive voltage to the MOSFET gates. Your text says this comes from a push switch. It would be valuable to edit the schematic to show this switch to 15 V.
What you don't have (as shown) but need is a gate pull-down resistor. This is to discharge the gate-source capacitance (usually Ciss in datasheet) quickly, to disable the MOSFETs when the switch is released. That stops the MOSFETs being left partly on and drawing enough current to dissipate power to damage themselves, as well as not turn off as intended.
The resistor value should be low enough to discharge the two Ciss quickly, high enough not to dissipate excessive power when the switch is pressed.
Try (a) getting rid of the Zeners and 10K then (b) adding a 10K pull-down to your 15V node.
Even if this is not the root cause of your problem, it is a necessary and valuable circuit correction to make.

From its datasheet, the LTL-307EE LED has a forward voltage drop of 2..2.6 V at 20 mA. It therefore needs a current limit resistor. Otherwise it will draw excessive current that could destroy the MOSFET, though I'd expect the LED to go first but nonetheless...
It would also benefit from a much lower supply rail, to reduce the power dissipation in that resistor.
Add a 1K2 1 W resistor in series with each LED.

You state "The question is NOT about how to protect a N-MOSFET gate. Advice and suggestions are always welcome, of course, but the question is not about that. The question is about reading the data sheet to find parameters indicating a less fragile MOSFET gate."
Finally, having answered to try to resolve circuit problems then here instead is a recommended replacement circuit. It uses a current-driven BJT rather than voltage-tripped MOSFETs. The result is a simple circuit with protection.
It draws about 300 uA input trigger current through the switch, enough to drive a 20 mA LED load or much higher. The 330K across the BJT will discharge ESD. You can use a TVS but a resistor can discharge static completely rather than clamp it.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thabks for your reply. There is a gate pull down resistor. I forgot to include it in the schematic. It's 330K. I could try with a smaller value. But I have used this set up in the past without any problem. Here the only difference with previous set up is the lenght of the cable. Longest lenghts previousely used were about 5 or 6 meters. But here, there were strong ESD in the ceiling, I think because of the metallic structure.

I intentionally didn't show the switch because I don't want the discussion to be diverted into analysing the circuit. The schematic is there only to present the situation. The question is focused on the datasheet parameters which could be useful.

@Fredled The 330K is pretty high and is very low resistance to pull the gate down. I think the problem is related to this and the very long cable attached to the gate (noise, ESD). Do you use a resistor to apply a voltage to the gate? If not, that is also a design fault.

@Fredled, thanks and I understand your point but, as said, I recommend you make the changes listed anyway. Besides that, you need LED series resistors. And: please do modify your schematic to show what you actually have, otherwise no-one's got much chance :-)

@Codebeat, MOSFET gates benefit from a series resistor, it'd be more a design fault to not have one. Especially with a higher voltage load up a long cable. It's nothing to do with limiting current like a BJT needs, though.

@Codebeat Yes, there was one 1K resistor at the 15V source, later replaced by 10K, and there was 100R resistor right before the gate, later replaced by 1K. After more failure, I added the Zener between the two resistors. And it didn't help. Only by adding 10K + the Zener helped, but I didn't test a lot because it was today. I will try with a lower pull down resistor as you suggest.

@TonyM Please ignore the LED part. It's not related to the problem. There is a regulator on the LED. "LTL-307EE" is not the LED that I use, but the name that comes by default on the editor. (Another thing I forgot to correct). You are right that completing the schematic would be useful. But it should be noted that this set up has been used several times without any issue and running for a long time.

@Fredled, one of the truly horrifying things you find in engineering is someone saying, "It's worked before for ages so must be OK" and actually refusing to improve it :-) Designing things that work is relatively easy, it's designing things that never don't work that's the goal. Here, you've modified it slightly and it doesn't work so that's included in the overall failure rate of both circuits. Let's (a) get the circuit right please, take you so little time, then (b) try corrected components. If the fault's not where you expect it to be, it must be where you don't expect.Am aiming to help :-)

@TonyM In fact, I wanted to know if there is a difference among N-MOSFET, specifically in SOT23 package but not only, regarding gate robustness, ESD tolerance and so on and if there are data able to show that in the datasheets (beyond Vgs). I will probably post the complete schematic in a separate question oriented on the improvement of the circuit. But before doing that, I wanted to know if the MOSFET I chose was a wrong one or not the best one.

@Fredled, it's not that separable and it's a tiny circuit so much easier to cover it all in one question, which is what we've been doing anyway so mostly done. Just need you to try out these changes and come back with results...

@Fredled, to your comment on choosing the best part, look at using a BJT instead as per my expanded answer. The current control makes it simpler than driving a FET over such distances.

Out of all the dimensions of a MOSFET, gate oxide insulator thickness is always the smallest. It’s less than 1/10th of other dimensions on mosfets in CMOS digital ICs, and an even smaller fraction for discrete parts. Gate oxide thickness affects threshold voltage proportionally. So, for a particular threshold voltage, it cannot be arbitrarily increased to make the gate more robust.
Connecting long cables to mosfet gates is thus an easy way to overstress them. Discrete mosfets have gate overvoltage protection structures but those can’t be arbitrarily robust either, since they increase gate leakage.
